# How to generate JWT token programatically in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter.
We've API tests written in Java+RestAssured and I have started creating separate JMeter tests for performance testing.

If we've ClientID & ClientSecret then how could I generate JWT token each time I've to run Jmenter tests?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at:

- [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) with [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)
- [authlete-jose](https://github.com/authlete/authlete-jose) library

See [Client authentication using client_secret_jwt method](https://kb.authlete.com/en/s/oauth-and-openid-connect/a/client-secret-jwt) article for comprehensive explanation and an example.